# Why does updating an external variable results in an error?

Tags: solidity, error

I'm trying to update a variable within an external contract.

My 2 contracts are as follow:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
contract MainContract {
string public variable1;

function setVariable1(string memory newValue) public {
    variable1 = newValue;
}}

contract SetContract {
//address MainContract;
MainContract myMainContract;  

constructor(
    address _myMainContract
) public {
    myMainContract = MainContract(_myMainContract);  
}

function setVariable1MainContract(string memory newValue) public {
    myMainContract.setVariable1(newValue);
}}
```

MainContracts holds the variable1 and de SetContract uses the setVariable1 function from MainContract.

When I deploy both contracts this works fine.

When I execute the function setVariable1MainContract I get an exception within Remix: "VM exception while processing transaction: revert".

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Extra info: ofcourse I have deployed the SetContract with a reference to MainContract via the constructor.

Comment: But have you deployed the MainContract?

Comment: Yes @goodvibration I deployed both contracts

Comment: Change `MainContract myMainContract` to `MainContract public myMainContract`, call `SetContract.myMainContract()` in Remix and let us know what you get.

Comment: Hi @goodvibration, I added 'public' and called SetContract.myMainContract() within the setVariable1MainContract function. Now I get a compiler error: Typeerror: type is not callable.

Comment: I meant that you should call `myMainContract()` using your instance of `SetContract`, **from Remix**!!!

Comment: Ohh... sorry . Executing myMainContract() from Remix gives me the right contract. Output is: addres: 0: address: 0x111b3c6b8a5E7d2d90DA3Fe2f7399CD86B7D8CcF (this is contract address of MainContract) @goodvibration

Comment: Your output description is not clear. I see two addresses, where there should be only one address returned from this function.

Comment: @goodvibration this is exactly the output from Remix. The contractaddress is: 0x111b3c6b8a5E7d2d90DA3Fe2f7399CD86B7D8CcF

Comment: You should be looking for the output of the function. The way you have described it (`The contractaddress is`) makes me suspect that you have just copy-pasted the address of the contract which you are calling the function with (i.e., the address of your `SetContract` instance).

Comment: @goodvibration I don't this this is the issue. I double checked the address and the address of SetContract is different than MainContract. While deploying SetContract I used address of MainContract. Do you know how I can get more error information from Remix after invoking the setVariable1MainContract function? Maybe this can give me more insights...

Comment: FWIW, I tried this in Remix, JavaScript VM, with the `0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1.Emscripten.clang` compiler. I deployed `MainContract`, then I deployed `SetContract`, passing the `MainContract` address as a parameter (unquoted string, starts with `0x`). Then I expanded `SetContract` and typed `"hello"` (with quotes) next to `setVariable1MainContract` and pressed that button. The transaction succeeded, and checking `variable` on `MainContract` returned the string `hello`. I used 3,000,000 as a gas limit on all transactions. I hope that helps. Good luck debugging!

Comment: Hi @smarx, thanks for your testing effort. I tested it again, without success. After this, I changed the Environment of Remix from Ganache to Javascript VM and guess what: IT WORKS!! Looks like an issue in Ganache. Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: I just tried it with `ganache`, and things worked fine for me again. But at leas that narrows it down a little? I ran `ganache-cli` with no parameters. Version string: "Ganache CLI v6.4.2 (ganache-core: 2.5.4)". I hope that helps narrow it down!

Comment: Hi @smarx, I just reinstalled Ganache and now everythinbg works fine. Thanks again, issue solved :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by an issue with Ganache. I reinstalled Ganache and the issue was resolved. Thanks for your help!!